# Вопрос о веб-программировании в будущем

Tags: веб-программирование

Возможно, для этого сайта вопрос будет немного нестандартен, но все же, я уже где то месяц думаю о том нужны ли будут веб-программисты, и будут ли они востребованы через лет так 7. Вы спросите, с чего такой большой срок? Ответ прост, сам я еще по сути школьник и учусь в 9ом классе, и как будущее направление в своей жизни выбрал именно программирование(не только веб, он только лишь начало), учится буду до 11го, потом в ВУЗ на лет так 5, вот и получается "срок" в 7 лет. И настигла меня мысль, а будет ли востребован веб когда я выпущусь? Возьмут ли меня на работу? И т.п.

---

Повторюсь, возможно вопрос глупый, и немного не соответствует тематике сайта, и лучше бы задал я его на Ответы сами-знаете-что.ru, но как ни как я волнуюсь  о своем будущем.

---

P.S.: Недавно был вебинар, на котором я тоже задал этот вопрос, мне ответили что "Да", но свою мысль никак не объяснили, поэтому если вы хотите написать "Да", то напишите почему, как и с ответом "Нет".

---

P.S.S.: В одном паблике увидел прототип бота который верстает сайты по макету из Фотошопа, конечно понятно что скрипты он не напишет, но все же...

Comment: Я б на вашем месте лучше бы начал учить как писать этих "ботов" (Насколько я помню это нейросеть).

Comment: "Знал бы прикуп, жил бы в сочи" :)

Comment: За 7 лет можно успеть изучить не только Web программирование. А еще пару десятков разных языков и поработать в множестве направлений. И может статься, что к окончанию вуза у вас будут совершенно другие интересы и предпочтения в выборе направления работы. Так что решать прямо сейчас, что вы будете именно Web-программистом нет никакого смысла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Будут ли востребованы web-программисты лет эдак через 7 ?

*Коротко:* будут востребованы программисты.

---

*Развернуто:* когда я свою профессию выбирал, то руководствовался следующими принципами:

- Что мне нравится делать, что мне интересно, что мне хочется изучать и куда мне хочется двигаться. То есть к чему душа лежит. Определить это просто - достаточно посмотреть на то, что у тебя лучше всего получается, чему ты и без того отдаешь больше всего времени.
- От чего ты не устаешь и чем можешь заниматься в любом состоянии или настроении, что не наскучит тебе когда ты уже все, что нужно, в этом будешь знать и уметь, что не будет тебя тяготить и с чем ты сможешь мириться.

---

Для меня было ответом: **компьютеры** - сначала я занимался сборкой, настройкой и продажами hardware и peripherals, потом понемногу начал админить (т.е. эникейщиком работал), потом начал работать с ПО. Сначала консультировал пользователей и занимался обслуживанием известных реляционных СУБД и ERP систем, потом перешел на backend для коммерческого ПО, к которому потом добавил frontend.

Мне нравится увязывать это все между собой.

---

Сейчас я для себя понял то, что в `айтях` на самом деле не так много  путей, и технологии не сменяют друг друга **революционно**, но идет плавное развитие, и одно из другого постепенно вытекает. Просто имеет смысл *держать нос по ветру* и изучать не только какую-то одну технологию и только ее, но и смотреть на смежные вещи, связанные с ней, или может быть не связанные, но интересные.

В любом случае, если ты действительно хочешь создать что-то серьезное, то тебе нужен **кругозор**, т.е. как минимум по чуть-чуть нужно знать ото всюду, а дальше, как моя бабушка говорила: *ближе к делу бог ума прибавит*.